# Send request to wordnet

Tags: beautifulsoup, wordnet

I need to get send a request on wordnet knowing the tar_id (taken from Imagenet) to get the lemma assigned to that tar (e.g., I have a tar with houses, I need to send the request and obtain the lemma written on wordnet "living accommodation").

I used requests.get() first, with the URL. Then BeautifulSoup's parser.

I get the parsed HTML as a return but, there is no reference to the "body", meaning the part of the Noun and hypernyms / hyponyms.

Can you tell me how to get that part of Wordnet parsed with the rest of the page?

This is the URL I'm working on: http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/pwn30/03546340-n

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `JSON` endpoint.

For example:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0",
}

url = "http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/json/pwn30/03546340-n"
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
print(data[0]["definition"])
```

Output:

```
structures collectively in which people are housed
```

And if you switch the endpoint to

```py
url = "http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/json_rel/03551520-n"
```

You'll get all the word relation data.